# How to configure Postfix on Ubuntu 16.04, to send mail from a Java webapp

Tags: java, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

here's my issue.

I have a Java web application which should send some mail notifications for various purposes. To that end, I've added apache's commons-email artifact.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

On the other hand, it is deployed on Ubuntu 16.04 where there is a postfix installation. Here is the main.cf. I've cleaned three words, replaced for the generic, which are:

- servername
- project
- domain

but in my configuration file ar also one word each, nothing odd.

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/path/to/certs/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/path/to/certs/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = servername.members.linode.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = servername.domain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost, project.domain.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Finally my question: How can I configure this postfix installation, so that my Java code needs no authentication, or if it does (even better), where/how can I set it?

Am I on the wrong direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the IP address of your Java web application to the mynetworks parameter:

```
   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

Then issue a

```
   postfix reload
```

The first restriction to trigger will be "permit_mynetworks" and the mail will be let through!

Comment: I've hired someone who solved it, but I don't know how. A postfix installation was installed on the same server in the end.